# shared c constants in a header

Tags: c, header, constants, string-literals

I want to share certain C string constants across multiple c files. The constants span multiple lines for readability:

```
const char *QUERY = "SELECT a,b,c "
                    "FROM table...";
```

Doing above gives redefinition error for QUERY. I don't want to use macro as backspace '\' will be required after every line. I could define these in separate c file and extern the variables in h file but I feel lazy to do that.

Is there any other way to achieve this in C?

Comment: Header files as Armen says - check his answer.

Comment: Note that in C++ global `const` implies `static` implicitly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042549/define-constant-variables-in-c-header/53541011#53541011

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In some .c file, write what you've written. 
In the appropriate .h file, write

```
extern const char* QUERY; //just declaration
```

Include the .h file wherever you need the constant

No other good way :)
HTH

Comment: :( I thought so. Guess I need to stop being so lazy!

Comment: @Manish:: Its better than writing the declaration in every `.c` files. And you know `Ctrl+C` -- `Ctrl+V` also works.

Comment: +1 you can have any colour you want as long as it's black LOL

Comment: @Acme: Ctrl+C -- Ctrl+V is exactly the thing I want to avoid. I know that if I change it in one c file, I'll forget to change it in other which will lead to a debugging nightmare.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a tool to generate the header files?

Answer (score 18):

You could use static consts, to all intents and purposes your effect will be achieved.

myext.h:

```
#ifndef _MYEXT_H
#define _MYEXT_H
static const int myx = 245;
static const unsigned long int myy = 45678;
static const double myz = 3.14;
#endif
```

myfunc.h:

```
#ifndef MYFUNC_H
#define MYFUNC_H
void myfunc(void);
#endif
```

myfunc.c:

```
#include "myext.h"
#include "myfunc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(void)
{
    printf("%d\t%lu\t%f\n", myx, myy, myz);
}
```

myext.c:

```
#include "myext.h"
#include "myfunc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\t%lu\t%f\n", myx, myy, myz);
    myfunc();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is one downside to this approach. If the constant isn't used in a compilation unit, some compilers will throw a warning which cannot be silenced without resorting to compiler specifics.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply `#define` them separate

```
#define QUERY1 "SELECT a,b,c "
#define QUERY2 "FROM table..."
```

and then join them in one definition

```
#define QUERY QUERY1 QUERY2
```

Comment: That is quite creative :) but it looks ugly.

Comment: Ugly and "backspace '\'" go hand-in-hand :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways

- place your variables in one file, declare them extern in the header and include that header where needed
- consider using some external tool to append '\' at the end of your macro definition
- overcome your laziness and declare your variables as extern in all your files