# How to read constant from another c++ file in android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am using NDK in my android app .  There was no problem . Here is the code for c++ file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_examples_core_MyApplication_getKeyJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string secret_key = "mysecret";
    return env->NewStringUTF(secret_key.c_str());
}
```

**Edit**

Here is my approach

my **native-lib.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h> // for getcwd()
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "constants.h"

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_examples_core_MyApplication_getKeyJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string secret_key = secret_key;
    return env->NewStringUTF(secret_key.c_str());
}
```

my **constants.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

extern const std::string secret_key;        // declaration
```

my **constants.cpp**

```
#include "constants.h"

const std::string secret_key = "mysecret";  // definition
```

When I compile I get the following error

```
native-lib.cpp:13: undefined reference to `secret_key'
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5499530/6950238).

Comment: I tried but didn't work , this is the error I got `constants.h:25:14: error: unknown type name 'string'; did you mean 'jstring'?` @AndriiOmelchenko

Comment: _"this is the error I got"_ You're referring to code that you haven't shown us, so we can't know what you did wrong.

Comment: @Michael I have share my full code.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to add `constants.cpp` to the source files that should be compiled.

Comment: Please include the command line used to link your project. It's often shown right before the linker errors (an undefined reference is a linker error).

Comment: @Michael thanks , I really did so :( . Now my problem is solved .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to put the definition in a header file, as that could lead to multiple definitions of the same variable.

But you could do something like this:

**constants.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

extern const std::string secret_key;        // declaration
```

**constants.cpp**

```
#include "constants.h"

const std::string secret_key = "mysecret";  // definition
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "constants.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << secret_key;               // usage
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I tried your solution , but couldn't solve . I have edited my question. Could you kindly have a look ?