# Printing out an array of pointers defined in header file

Tags: c, pointers

I'm currently working on a DBMS as a college project, I'm having issues at printing out an array of strings which is defined in an header file.

I've tried playing around with pointers but I guess the problem is within the definition of the array, which being in another file can't be retrieved properly.

Here's metacommand.h file

```
typedef enum {NORMAL, DB, TABLE} Mode;

const char* normalModeMetaCommands[] = {".help", ".exit", ".db-mode", ".table-mode"};
const char* dbModeMetaCommands[] = {".help", ".exit", ".workingdir", ".dbs", ".db"};
const char* tableModeMetaCommands[] = {".help", ".exit", ".tables", ".table", ".index", ".select"};

const char* getModeName(Mode mode);
const char* getModeInputPrompt(Mode mode);
const char* getModeMetaCommands(Mode mode);

static void print_metacommands();
```

And here's some snippets from database.c file

```
static Mode mode = NORMAL;
```

```
const char* getModeMetaCommands(Mode mode) 
{
   switch (mode) 
   {
      case NORMAL: return *normalModeMetaCommands;
      case DB: return *dbModeMetaCommands;
      case TABLE: return *tableModeMetaCommands;
   }
}
```

```
static void print_metacommands(){

    size_t size = sizeof(getModeMetaCommands(mode))/sizeof(getModeMetaCommands(mode)[0]);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf("%s\n", getModeMetaCommands(mode)[i]);
    }

}
```

I have defined some functions that change the enum value in the database.c file, so that in each mode (NORMAL, DB and TABLE) I can print out an exclusive list of metacommands.

EDIT

My function `print_metacommands()` doesn't print those char pointers array (*normalModeMetaCommands[], *dbModeMetaCommands[], *tableModeMetaCommands[]).
Output is a segFault.

If I change:

```
const char* getModeMetaCommands(Mode mode);
```

to:

```
const char** getModeMetaCommands(Mode mode);
```

And:

```
const char* getModeMetaCommands(Mode mode) 
{
   switch (mode) 
   {
      case NORMAL: return *normalModeMetaCommands;
      case DB: return *dbModeMetaCommands;
      case TABLE: return *tableModeMetaCommands;
   }
}
```

to:

```
const char** getModeMetaCommands(Mode mode) 
{
   switch (mode) 
   {
      case NORMAL: return normalModeMetaCommands;
      case DB: return dbModeMetaCommands;
      case TABLE: return tableModeMetaCommands;
   }
}
```

The output is only ".help" because it seems like:

```
size_t size = sizeof(getModeMetaCommands(mode))/sizeof(getModeMetaCommands(mode)[0]);
//evaluated to: size=1
```

So, how can I print out those char pointers array via `static void print_metacommands();`?

Comment: What is your question? What happens and how does it differ from your expectation?

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499504/shared-c-constants-in-a-header

Comment: We need a full program, not just snippets.

Comment: Gabriele Biagini, what JL2210 is trying to tell you is that making an answer would be much easier and probably more to the point, if you would make a [mcve] to demonstrate your problem. (@JL2210 try typing `[mcve]` in a comment like that)

Comment: Sorry for not being much clear, I've reformulated the question entirely, hope this helps!

Comment: @Yunnosch I know about those: [mcve] [main] [meta], etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's many basic errors here.

- Never declare global variables anywhere, period.
- Never define variables (or functions) in header files. This always leads to various linking hiccups and bugs where different instances of variables with the same name co-exist in different translation units.

  Instead, move all variable definitions and initializations to file scope inside a .c file, make them `static` and only let the caller access them through setter/getter functions. They will no longer be global, but note that they are still not thread safe.
- You cannot use `sizeof` on a pointer, because pointers are not arrays. It gives the size of the pointer, not the length of the pointed-at string.